# Make Node.js Installer automatically install Chocolatey

Tags: node.js, installation, chocolatey

I'm trying to deploy the official Windows Node.js installer to Windows user, but the problem is that although I want the installer to automatically install the bundled Chocolatey, but the option checkbox for installing it is always unchecked.

How can I make the installer default to installing Chocolatey instead?

Comment: Im tried and i can check the checkbox, your checkbox is dissabled or what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @JorgeMontejo I want the checkbox to be checked by default so I can automate the installation with Chocolatey